# почему каждый раз при смене языка с основого на другой добавляется public кроме языковой метки? Laravel

Tags: laravel

на локальном такого нет, а вот на сервере, залит сайт в public html

я заливаю laravel

потом сразу если открыть по url ошибка, а если добавить site/public тогда откроется

поэтому я делаю перенаправление на public через htaccess

на английской верии

site.com/

все ок

а если ме6няем язык

получается

site.com/public/de

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить на это

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: спасибо даже не пробовал, вопрос решили на сервере